# Does the version field in package.json overwrite/set the version number in gradle/ios when NOT using Expo to develop a React Native app?

Tags: react-native, package.json

I have an React Native application that was created without using Expo. So, I have to manually manage a bunch of stuff. Not my choice.

I noticed that the package.json has a version field. However, as far as I understand, if I want to deploy my app to the app stores, I have to set the new versions in Android Studio and Xcode.

So, what's the point of the version number in package.json? Is it just like leaving yourself a note? Does it matter if you even use it?

Comment: In my workflow, I've never used package.json to handle versioning. However, there are scripts like [this](https://github.com/stovmascript/react-native-version) that can apply the version in `package.json` to the build.gradle and info.plist.